# Threading and Django db create operations

Tags: python, django, multithreading, postgresql

I have a python script which collects information for actors from various APIs (wikipedia, tmdb and imdb) then adds them to a postgresql database. It worked well but was sometimes a little slow due to all the API requests.

So I altered this script to use threading, however running it now produces the following error:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Am I hitting the database too much in a short space of time perhaps? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow more connetions in your `postgresql.conf` by increasing value of `max_connections`.

**UPDATED:**

You may also need to increase the SHMMAX value. Run this command from terminal:

```
sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=1073741824
```

This will set SHMMAX to 1G. Tune this according to your RAM size.

Comment: Tried and failed there: "2013-10-13 17:57:59 BST FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Invalid argument
2013-10-13 17:57:59 BST HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMMAX parameter.  You can either reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMMAX.  To reduce the request size (currently 34955264 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
If the request size is already small, it's possible that it is less than your kernel's SHMMIN...

Comment: Try to run this command in terminal: `sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=1073741824`. This will set SHMMAX to 1G. Tune this according to your RAM size.